# Infinite Loop due to cout<<cin.rdbuf(), why?

Tags: c++, io, stream, console

i write a program for read input from console and write agian on console. So i used following code.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout<<cin.rdbuf();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

but it goes in infinite loop. always getting input and printing it back. can anyone explain , what is happening here ?

it generate following output:

(wait for input : enter g)

```
g
g
```

(again wait for input : enter h (any char))

```
h
h
```

(still wait for input : enter h (any char))

```
h
h
```

so on, program always wait for input when i enter any charecter it just print it. again wait for input. it do not terminate

Comment: What is your desired behavior?

Comment: How do you *know* there is infinite loop? Does it print "infinite loop" as output? :|

Comment: http://ideone.com/UpFsFS it definitely produces output - running locally it repeats entire lines

Comment: It works for me, both with g++ and MSC.  How are you generating end of file?  (You won't return from the `<<` until the streambuf on the left returns end of file or an error.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `rdbuf()` returns a `std::streambuf*`.  The `<<` copies from that until it encounters end of file.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting behaviour. 
With your line `cout<<cin.rdbuf();` you are calling: `ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );`

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/:

(2) stream buffers
    Retrieves as many characters as possible from the input sequence controlled by the stream buffer object pointed by sb (if any) and inserts them into the stream, until either the input sequence is exhausted or the function fails to insert into the stream.
    Internally, the function accesses the output sequence by first constructing a sentry object. Then (if good), it inserts characters into its associated stream buffer object as if calling its member function sputc, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.

I assume internally this function calls some kind of getString on the streambuffer in a loop. This one will probably wait for key inputs and forward them to the ostream. The streambuffer is never empty but waits for some user input.

For an exact answer, the implementaiton of the << operator should be read.

Comment: You don't need to read the implementation; it is more or less obvious given the specification.

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure what is meant by "until the input sequence is exhausted".

Comment: Until there is no more input available.  End of file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you're generating an end of file on standard
in?  The definition of `<<` on an `std::streambuf*` is to read
until end of file on the streambuf.  Basically, it is something
along the lines of:

```
while ( sb->sgetc() != EOF ) {
    this->rdbuf()->sputc( sb->sbumpc() );
}
```

This is simplified; an actual implementation will have to do
error checking on the `sputc`, and set `iostate` bits in the
destination as well, according to what has actually happened.
But this is a basic abstraction.  And for optimization reasons,
a real implementation will probably use `sgetn` instead of `sgetc`/`sbumpc`.